# How to foreach this data

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

The extraction values are separate and non-duplicated

[this my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5EAF.png)

When it is extracted it is like this

[When it is extracted it is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBfxx.png)

I want to be like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QppMX.png)

Please apply to this example

```
<div class="scrolling menu">
 @foreach($genres as $genre)
   <a href="{{ url('cinema/movies/genre/'.$genre->genre) }}" class="item">{{ $genre->genre }}</a>
 @foreach
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select one of the values from the CSV list in that column? If so, what is the criteria to determine which value in the CSV list to return? If not, please explain more what you want done. You have a column in your table that has a CSV list of genres, and in the results you want a column that has single genre results, but what exactly are you wanting in that list? All the genres in the result set?

Comment: Also, what is the current SQL select you are using?

Comment: @AsherMaximum did you see the pictures, I want to extract the values from the genre column and all values are separate and not repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Good Enough" Answer:**
If you are just trying to solve the problem at hand and nothing more, then you can use some readily available PHP functions like `explode` and `trim` to help you.

```
 @php $trackedGenres = array(); @endphp
 @foreach($genres as $genre)
   @php $splitGenres = explode(",", $genre->genre); @endphp
   @for ($i = 0; $i < count($splitGenres); $i++)
      @php $thisGenre = trim($splitGenres[$i], " "); @endphp
      @if (!in_array($thisGenre, $trackedGenres))
          @php $trackedGenres[] = $thisGenre; @endphp
          <a href="{{ url('cinema/movies/genre/'.$thisGenre) }}" class="item">{{ $thisGenre }}</a>
      @endif
   @endfor
 @foreach
```

---

**Better Answer:**
If you have control over your database schema, I would recommend creating a separate table to hold normalized genre values like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Genre
(
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
);
```

Then create a MovieGenre table to link movies with genres, which would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MovieGenre
(
   MovieId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   GenreId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(MovieId, GenreId),
   FOREIGN KEY (MovieId) REFERENCES cinema_movie(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (GenreId) REFERENCES genre(id)
);
```

Obviously with a separate Genre table (and active record class, I'm assuming) you'll be able to get a unique list of genres.
Then you'd just have to establish a has_many in your Movie class and you should be able to get all the genres tied to a particular movie.

Comment: Can you arrange the code? It does not conform to Laravel Blade Templates https://imgur.com/cKoxyLe

Comment: @AliTalib Sure, I updated my closing tags to endif and endfor, oversight on my part.

Comment: you can fix that https://i.imgur.com/IFSjXs0.png You are solving this problem but correct the code so that it fits with Laravel Blade

Comment: @AliTalib Is there a reason you can't fix it yourself? I don't use Laravel, and honestly my opinion is that your choice of framework doesn't really reflect what your actual question was about.

Comment: @AliTalib Never mind, I've updated it, though I still stand by my previous comment that the fact you are using Laravel is irrelevant to your actual issue.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my problem

Comment: In fact, I did not find a better and faster frame. Yes, you are right. There are problems but I deal with them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
@foreach($genres as $genre)
    <a href="{{ url('cinema/movies/genre/'.$genre->genre) }}" class="item">
        @if($trimmed = explode(',', $genre->genre, 2))
            {{ $trimmed[0] }}
        @endif
     </a>
@foreach
```

And you also have to cover situation if the genre is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this the proper way with PHP + MySQL before you output in the HTML. You will have to use PDO or whatever database wrapper you're using. Essentially you want this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT genre FROM cinema_movies
```

Store that in a variable (array) called `$rows`;

Then loop through and build a unique list

```
$categories = [];

foreach ($rows as $r) {
  $categories = array_merge($categories, explode(", ", $r));
}

$unique_cats = array_unique($categories)
```

Comment: @AliTalib Why not? Laravel is an MVC framework for PHP, so any code that runs in PHP will run in Laravel. Is the issue that you just wouldn't know where to use this code?

Comment: That's true Thank you